# Hacer un print de todos los elementos

Tags: python

```
from datetime import date,datetime
fechas=[]
n = int(input("Ingrese el numero de fechas que desea agregar a la lista :"))
for i in range(n):
        ano=int(input("Por favor ingrese el año :"))
        mes=int(input("Por favor ingrese el mes :"))
        dia=int(input("Por favor ingrese el dia :"))
        nueva_fecha= datetime(ano,mes,dia)
        fechas.append(nueva_fecha)
print(fechas)
for i in range(len(fechas)):
        for j in range (len(fechas)-1):
            if fechas[j]<fechas[j+1]:
                tmp=fechas[j]
                fechas[j] = fechas [j+1]
                fechas[j+1]=tmp
print(fechas[0].strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))
```

Necesito que en el ultimp print, muestre todas las fechas que esten agregadas ya he intentado de varias maneras y no se como lograrlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tendrías que recorrer la lista `fechas` y convertir de *Datetime* a *string*, para ello nos apoyamos de una expresión generador y usamos el método `"\n".join()` para poder unirlos mediante un salto de linea.

```
print("\n".join(fecha.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") for fecha in fechas))
```